# How to add language to nokia asha 306?

Tags: language

I have a Nokia 306 Asha that I bought for my sister and she doesn't know english at all and the only understandable(by me) language that it has is english.

I saw some descriptions by using PC Suite,Nokia Software Updater,Nemesis Service Suite to change the Product Code so it would have other languages. The only problem is that in the tutorials they didn't described for which phones is this and I can't find the Product Code for Romania or Hungary.
I found some Produt Codes but I don't know which of them could be for Romania or Hungary.

The Product Codes look like this:

> 059L9F6: RM-768 LATAM_L_MBLUE_NULL_LTA
>   059L9F7: RM-768 LATAM_L_RED_NULL_LTA
>   059L9F8: RM-768 LATAM_L_DGREY_NULL_LTA
>   059L8S7: RM-767 EURO_D_DGREY_NULL_MK
>   059L8S8: RM-767 EURO_D_DGREY_NULL_HR
>   059L8S9: RM-767 EURO_D_DGREY_NULL_RS
>   059L8T0: RM-767 EURO_C_DGREY_NULL_FR
>   059M834: RM-767_EURO_D_RED_NULL_CZ
>   059M835: RM-767_EURO_D_DGREY_NULL_CZ
>   059N0R9: RM-767 MEA_MAA_SY_NULL_RED
>   059N0S0: RM-767 MEA_MAA_SD_NULL_RED
>   059N0S1: RM-767 MEA_MAA_SY_NULL_DGREY

How can I tell which of the Product Codes are good?

Comment: Try the ones with "EURO" in it. Since "LATAM" im betting means Latin America and "MEA" is Middle East.

Comment: Its one of those things that slips through the cracks, but phone questions (except where the phone is a periphral for a PC) are off topic for SU. Unfortunately I can't think of a better fit for the question elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that there are two versions of the Nokia Asha one is the RM-767, and the other one is the RM-768. If you want to change the language to Romanian you probably have the European version which is the RM-767.

If you have a grey handset, use the `059L8S9: RM-767 EURO_D_DGREY_NULL_RS` product code to install the Russian language pack (includes: English, German, Ukrainian, Russian, Romanian, Bulgarian, Hungarian) and go to phone settings, and change to your desired language.

For more colors check [this](http://mrcrab.net/nokia/Nokia_Asha_306.html?productType=RM-767&releaseID=7062880838&version=3.63) page, remember to check the language code (last part of file name) `Rs` for Russia, `Ro` for Romania, and `Hr` for Hungary.